# Why do I get a dark image when using inverse fourier transform ifft2() in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, lowpass-filter

I believe there's something wrong when I convert it back using ifft2(). I am trying to use the ideal low-pass filter by creating a matrix L that has a circle with 1's with the radius 50. It would be great if you guys can tell me what the issue is. Thanks!

```
I0 = imread('image.png');
g = I0(:,:,1);
Rg = imref2d(size(g));


G = fft2(g);
AG1 = log(1+abs(G));
MaxVal = max(max(AG1));

AG2 = uint8(255*(AG1/MaxVal));
SAG2 = fftshift(AG2);


%zero matrix L with a circle with value 1's with radius 50 
[xGrid,yGrid] = meshgrid(1:400,1:400);
L = sqrt((xGrid - 200).^2 + (yGrid - 200).^2) <= 50;

U = uint8(double(SAG2).*L);
a=ifft2(U);


u = uint8(real(ifft2(U)));

imshow(u,'InitialMagnification',300);
```

Comment: I am not sure what is EXACTLY wrong with your code, but I can tell you 1 think that definetly is: the continous use of `uint8`. Your maths will break if you just use integers. Use double for all the maths, then convert to uint8 in the end if you want (by scaling, not casting!!!)

Comment: What @Ander said is especially true for the Fourier transform. Casting the frequency data to `uint8` makes no sense. You are also inverse-transforming the scaled logarithm of the magnitude of the frequency data, instead of the actual frequency data.  And when you apply `fftshift`, you also need to use `ifftshift` before inverse transforming.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking a whole bunch of unnecessary actions. As mentioned in the comments, all the `int8` castings are redundant. You are also missing an `ifftshift` in the calculation of `u`. Here is a short version that does the low-passing you want:

```
I0 = imread('your_file.png');
g = I0(:,:,1);

G = fft2(g);

SAG2 = fftshift(G);

%zero matrix L with a circle with value 1's with radius 50 
[xGrid,yGrid] = meshgrid(1:400,1:400);
L = sqrt((xGrid - 200).^2 + (yGrid - 200).^2) <= 50;

U = SAG2 .* L;

u = real(ifft2(ifftshift(U)));

figure
imshow(u,[]);
```